# React Native Android opacity issue

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a loading view with a translucent background,
but only Android doesn't apply opacity to the textinput

**ios**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXci4.png
*It should be implemented like this.*

**android**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKF92.png

```
<Cantainer>
  ...
  
  {loading &&
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', opacity: 0.3, backgroundColor: '#000', width: '100%', height: height}}>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" style={{top: '35%'}} />
    </View>
  }
</Cantainer>
```

Comment: Add backgroundColor as `#00000040`.

Comment: It's not working. Textinput still doesn't become translucent.

Comment: You have given elevation to TextInput style right? give higher elevation for loading Vie style too

Comment: Oh, my. You're a genius. Thank you.